# First error: Exceeded maximum time allotted for callout (120000 ms)

Tags: apex, batch, callout, schedulebatch, timeout

I have a Batch class making an API callout and I have scheduled this class. I have used a for loop to iterate through the page number variable in my API endpoint. There are 64 pages. Strangely, if I use for(integer i=1; i<=64;i++) I get an error, but it works perfectly fine with for(integer i=1; i<=35;i++) or any lower value than 35 for i. I have tried changing my batch size but doesn't help.

These are my classes:

Batch Class:

```
  global class ImportReports implements Database.Batchable<Reports__c>, Database.AllowsCallouts 
  {

      global static HTTPResponse getReports(String api)
      {


        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();      
        req.setEndpoint(api);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(120000);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);


         return res;      


      }




  global List<Reports__c> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
  { 

    List<Reports__c> reportsToAdd = new List<Reports__c>();


    for(integer i=1; i<=32;i++)
    {

        String allReportsString = getReports('https://api.example.com/v1/reports/page[number]='+i).getBody();

        WrapperClass allReports = WrapperClass.parse(recentReports);



        for(WrapperClass reportInArray : allReports)
        {
            Reports__c rep = new Reports__c(); 

            rep.id__c = reportInArray.id;


            reportsToAdd.add(rep);
            System.debug(reportInArray.id);
        }



    }


   return reportsToAdd; 


  }    


   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Reports__c> scope)
   {

        try 
      {
            upsert scope;
      } 

      catch (DmlException e) 
      {
              // Process exception here
         }

    }     

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {     
    } 
}
```

Scheduling Class:

```
global class SchedulerClass implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts{

    public static String sched = '0 11 11 * * ?'; 


        global static String scheduleBatch() {
        SchedulerClass SC = new SchedulerClass(); 
        return System.schedule('Insert Reports', sched, SC);
    }    


    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {

        ImportReports b = new ImportReports ();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(b,50);   




    }

  }
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 7):

The callout timeout is tricky, because it applies both to [single callouts and as a cumulative limit across a transaction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm):

> The maximum cumulative timeout for callouts by a single Apex transaction is 120 seconds. This time is additive across all callouts invoked by the Apex transaction.

Here, it looks like you're running into the *cumulative* version of this limit. You can send up to ~35 (the number probably varies slightly depending on network speed and server load) callouts in a single transaction because each one takes a little under 4 seconds, on average, to complete.

You're currently doing all of this work in your `start()` method. You need to make some architectural changes to split this work across multiple transactions in order to complete it successfully. `start()` runs in a single transaction, and is intended to return a query or iterator that defines the objects which will be split into separate batches, each of which is processed via `execute()` in a separate transaction.

Inasmuch as you're not iterating over batches of sObjects, I would actually suggest making this into a Queueable chain rather than a batch class. Basically, what you'd do is make a Queueable Apex class like this:

```
public class MyQueueable implements Queueable {
    Integer startNumber = 0;
    Integer endNumber = 0;

    public MyQueueable(Integer start, Integer end) {
        startNumber = start;
        endNumber = end;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // make your callouts here - 
        // process, say, 30, then chain into a new Queueable:
        for (Integer i = startNumber; i < endNumber && i < startNumber + 30; i++) {
            // Do callout and store result
        }

        insert results; // however we accumulated them.
        // Check if we have more work to do and recurse.
        if (i < endNumber) {
            System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(startNumber + i, endNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very rough sketch, but I think the pattern will be more applicable to your challenge than Batch Apex as you're trying to use it.